# Difference between these two op amp circuits

Tags: operational-amplifier, single-supply-op-amp

I came across this circuit for a non inverting op amp which is biased Vs/2. I'm wondering what the difference bettween these two circuits are? What is the purpose of R3 in the first circuit and how is it different to the second circuit?

Thank you
[image]

Comment: To understand how R3 is calculated from R4 and R5 (it's on the sheet!), assume both Vs and GND are at Vbias instead.

Answer (score 1):

They're both the same.  The first circuit assumes a Vbias supply is available independently.  The second provides it from Vs as a Thevenin equivalent.  In this case, R4||R5 = R3, and Vbias = Vs*R5/(R4+R5) if the circuits are to be functionally identical.

Answer (score 0):

In case R3=R4||R5=R3/2 both circuits provide the same gain - however, the first circuit uses dual power supplies (+ - Vs) and can work with Vbias=0 (ground), whereas the second one can work with one supply voltage only. Therefore, the second one needs a DC bias voltage at the non-inv. input for biasing the output DC at Vs/2 (R4=R5).

As a consequence, the input resistance of the 2nd amplifier is reduced to R4||R5.

Comment: How can you determine what power supplies are being used from those circuits? Neither shows any detail at all.

Comment: Yes - you are right. However, what do you think could be the purpose of the additional resistors R3, R4, R5 ?  To me, the answer is clear (as written above in my comment.)

Comment: Both circuits will work fine from single or split rail supplies. The bias may be needed because a single rail is being used, or it may be because whatever Vo is driving needs to have the signal biased, e.g. an A/D converter on an MCU.